# How to use an icon instead of the original back button in React Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to display a FontAwesome icon instead of the default chevron icon in the header of React Navigation.

I've tried to override the `headerLeft` prop in the `screenOptions`, but the back button was displayed all the time, and lost the ability to go back to the previous screen. I just want to keep the original back button behaviour (displayed only on nested screens), but with a custom icon.

I've came up with this (doesn't work of course):

```js
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const screenOptions = {
  headerBackTitleVisible: false,
  headerBackImageSource: () => (
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowAltCircleLeft} color="#fff" size={24} />
  ),
};

export const CategoriesStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={screenOptions}>
      <Stack.Screen name={Routes.Categories} component={Categories} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Routes.Category}
        component={Category}
        options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.id })}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={Routes.CategoryAbout}
        component={CategoryAbout}
        options={({ route }) => ({ title: route.params.category })}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

The doc is a bit unclear on this topic and I don't find good exemple on the web. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
const screenOptions = {
  headerBackImage: () => (
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faArrowAltCircleLeft} color="#fff" size={24} />
  ),
};
```

here is slack [demo](https://snack.expo.dev/@nilesh.nvs/2ca61d)

Comment: @DoneDeal0 glad i could help you :)

Comment: @NileshPatel my case not working <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
              headerShown : false,
              headerBackVisible:true,
              headerLeft: ()=>(
                <Icon name="chevron-left"
                      onPress={() => navigation.goBack(null)}
                      size={35} color="white"/>
             )
            }}>

Comment: @DharmeshDhameliya are you using expo or react-native?